# Эффективное объединение двух больших булевых списков

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется два двумерных **больших** списка, содержащих **True** или **False**, например:

```
arr1 = [[False,True,False,True,False,False],[False,True,True,True,False,False]...]
arr2 = [[False,False,True,False,True,False],[True,False,True,True,True,False]...]
```

На выходе должно получиться:

```
arr = [[False,True,True,True,True,False],True,True,True,True,True,False]...]
```

В алгоритме важна скорость, поэтому перебор через обычный цикл for не подходит.
Есть ли какие-то библиотеки или встроенные функции которые могут это сделать быстрее цикла for?

Answer (score 3):

Ну используйте `numpy`. Но тогда хорошо бы, чтобы сами данные уже были сразу в его формате, иначе много времени потратится на преобразование и не факт, что будет выигрыш:

```py
import numpy as np

n = 10_000_000
k = 10
arr1 = np.random.choice([True, False], (n, k))
arr2 = np.random.choice([True, False], (n, k))
arr3 = arr1 | arr2
```

Comment: Что означают переменные `n = 10_000_000` и `k = 10`  и почему именно такие значения?

Comment: @ClassicНастоящий 10 миллионов массивов по 10 элементов. Чисто для примера. Считается практически моментально.

Answer (score 0):

Решение было найдено, с помощью `numpy` и функции `np.logical_or(arr1,arr2)`

Comment: Это тоже самое, что `arr1 | arr2`, если что ))